# php preg match with inline matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I match only the exact inline code and match the two if's twice, not as one match.

http://regexr.com?2uvul

I want to get result with:

Array(
[0] => asd
[1] => asd
)

not

Array(
[0] => asdasd
)

Comment: It would be helpful to future user of this site if you would paste the sample code and expressions you tried into the question above. Use the back-tick character (on the `~` key) to quote text or code or indent code by four or more spaces to set it out from the rest of the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://regexr.com?2uvuu -- use the expression:

```
<!--\s+IF\s+([^\s]*)\s-->([^<]*)<!--\sENDIF\s-->
```

**EDIT:**

Considering that what you want to match inside the if statement "tag" might have white space, a slightly slower expression that should handle anything inside the "if statement" should be as follows (at [RegExr](http://regexr.com?2uvvv)):

```
/<!--\s+IF\s+(.*?)\s-->([^<]*)<!--\sENDIF\s-->/gixsm
```

If you then want to be able to capture other tags (or the character `<`) inside the result (if the statement is "true", you will want to use the (again slightly slower) expression (at [RegExr](http://regexr.com?2v005)):

```
/<!--\s+IF\s+(.*?)\s-->(.*?)<!--\sENDIF\s-->/gixsm
```

**END EDIT**

Comment: What about <!-- IF test == 3 -->asd<!-- ENDIF --> ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question was very incomplete, and I don't know what you are asking, so I suppose I gave an incomplete answer. I have no idea what might appear in your if "statement", because I do no know the syntax. I will try again!

Comment: Hi, sorry I've forgot to mention about this syntax, its pretty nested.Thanks about the perfect code! :)

Comment: Hi, sorry about the question again, but what about this: http://regexr.com?2v00e ? Tag inside tag.

Comment: If you're trying to nest 'if' logic, you're either going to have to find or define some way to make the ifs and endifs look different than each other, or you will have to use some type of actual parser. A complete solution is well beyond the scope of this comment, but differentiation could be accomplished by giving the beginning and ending if tags an ID of sorts like `<!-- IF(0) x == 5 --> <!-- IF(1) blah is true --> asdf <!-- ENDIF(1) --> ghjkl <!-- ENDIF(0) -->` doing this, you could match the beginning and ending tags to parse them separately. Also, please see my comment on your question.

Comment: The defining thing isn't really good, I'll try to think about something better, some background element counting. :) Thanks about the replies. :)